# Why is “temps” spelled with a final S?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe

Of all the Romance languages, only in French "time," *temps*, is spelled with a final *-s*, even when it's in the singular.

Is this French peculiarity etymological, morphological, phonetic, or a combination thereof?

Comment: I’ve hardly any idea what you’re asking. Do you mean “why does *‘temps’* ends with and s?” or something else entirely?

Comment: @Édouard Yes, why it has the _-s_ ending. (By the way, if you feel you can make my question more explicit, you're free to edit it thus).

Comment: I can do that. Please note, however, that despite the *s* in the end, it is not always plural.

Comment: If this is a bad question, please vote to close it. I already have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many nouns in French that have an *-s* ending but are singular.  Many of these nouns do not change when using singular or plural.  Note that '*temps*' does not change in the singular (*le temps*) and the plural (*les temps*).

**Etymology:**

**The French word '*temps*' comes from the Latin word '*tempus*', which also means '*time*' in English.**  This is the origin of the word.  As words from other languages are used, they can be modified slightly such as this.  '*Tempus*' in Latin, is singular however.  It's plural is '*tempora*'. (*Side note: Latin is also a romance language*)

**Other words in French with *-s* endings that are the same in singular or plural:**

- '*cours*'
- '*abattis*'

More information: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps#.C3.89tymologie